# How can I keep .h-files from changing into .h~ files?

Tags: c++, c, matlab

I have a problem with a C-Code which is included in Matlab. I got a program for the simulation of a batterymanagementsystem from another student at my university, that I have to use for my project.

There are a lot of (Header) .h and C-Source-Files (.c), which are included in the code.

```
#include "c1_BMS_atmel.h"
#include "c2_BMS_atmel.h"
```

... and so on. There are about forty of these files. And this is the point where the error occurs:

```
lcc preprocessor error: BMS_atmel_sfun.c:3 Could not find include file "c2_BMS_atmel.h"
```

The problem is, Windows (or something else) turns the c2_BMS_atmel.h into c2_BMS_atmel.h~. Every time I start the simulation there are different files, that change there ending and cannot be included.

The question is: How can I keep whatever it is from changing the files?

Comment: Download & lauch procmon from sysinternals.  Filter it to see all operations to the full path of one specific file ending in `.h~`.  Follow your workflow and create a file ending in `.h` with the same name otherwise.  What does procmon say created the `.h~` file?  (finding the spot to enter a path filter in procmon may take some effort, but I have faith you can figure it out)

Comment: What editor are you using? `emacs` leaves its backup files with a `~` at the end.